# How to obtain a list of URLs on a website (Air Bnb) - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, url

All,

I'm trying to obtain a list of all URLs displaying on the below link. I'd like to capture them and store them as a list. I currently am having to manually save them to an excel file and then load them in and have selenium loop through each URL. It's a bit cumbersome and I suspect there's a much more efficient python way to do it.

URL: https://www.airbnb.com/

I'm using edge and the below packages:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    from IPython.display import IFrame
    import re
    from io import StringIO
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium import webdriver
    import edgedriver_autoinstaller
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Providing some of your code and explaination were you get stuck would improve your question, as well as an expected output.

Comment: Use the requests module to get the content of the page, this content already has all the links for those images with following tag: "imageUrl" you just need to find a way to filter all those URLs, I think you can use re module to match the urls from the content.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.